# Is Amazon Chime SDK available for India?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, aws-chime-sdk

I wanted to build Video, audio calling and chat feature in my website and need some Communication SDK. So thought of using Azure Communication Services i.e ACS but it is not available for India and has data location as Asia Pacific so tried an alternative Amazon Chime SDK but now I can see that it has media region as Mumbai but I am not able to use it. So can anyone suggest some alternative what I can use?
Or confirm if Amazon Chime SDK is available or not for Indians.

Answer (score 0):

> To confirm if Amazon Chime SDK is available or not for Indians.

how about you use this which is recommended by amazon [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/chime-sdk-meetings-regions.html) too.

*Call *https://nearest-media-region.l.chime.aws* to identify the nearest media Region that can host your Amazon Chime SDK meeting. Make the call from the client application, not the server application.*

**Your request returns a JSON object showing the AWS Region that is nearest to you.**

```
async getNearestMediaRegion(): Promise<string> {
    var nearestMediaRegion = '';
    const defaultMediaRegion = 'us-east-1';
    try {
      const nearestMediaRegionResponse = await fetch(
        `https://nearest-media-region.l.chime.aws`,
        {
          method: 'GET',
        }
      );
      const nearestMediaRegionJSON = await nearestMediaRegionResponse.json();
      this.log(nearestMediaRegionJSON.region);
      nearestMediaRegion = nearestMediaRegionJSON.region;
    } catch (error) {
      nearestMediaRegion = defaultMediaRegion;
      this.log('Default media region ' + defaultMediaRegion + ' selected: ' + error.message);
    } finally {
      return nearestMediaRegion;
    }
  }
```

if the response returns `ap-south-1` which is for `the Mumbai region` then definitely you can use it for India.

> So can anyone suggest some alternative what I can use?

try this.
[Getting started tutorial](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/modules/gettingstarted.html) for chime-sdk by aws,and [their repo](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/index.html)

Comment: In your meeting service, create an AWS SDK Chime object. You must currently use us-east-1 as the region (you can select a Media Region in the following step).     <----                  Isn't the deployment region and media region different? Because meeting deployed from us-east can host the meetings in Media Regions i.e Mumbai. I have AISPL account and when I try to view Chime page the AWS says currently this service is not available for Indian customers.

Comment: I am creating Amazon connect instance. 'Build an amazon connect integration' but getting an error 'We're sorry. While we strive to make AWS’s broad set of products and services available to all customers, some products and services may not be available to customers in India, including customers of Amazon Internet Services Private Limited (AISPL). Currently, AISPL does not provide Amazon Connect.
Same error for Chime and Connect

Comment: what was the response of the json code? and alsoExactlyy, AWS chime currently is not suppoted by AISPL accounts, the only solution is to create a new account under AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Mumbai(ap-south-1) is supported to host Chime SDK meeting.
Refer to the region doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/chime-sdk-meetings-regions.html